# Can a class inherit from both an abstract class and a CRTP class?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, abstract-class, crtp

Can a class inherit from both an abstract class and a CRTP class?  Or if I inherit from a CRTP class must all classes I inherit from use CRTP?

Comment: Why didn't you test it? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

```
class AbstractBase {
public:
  virtual ~AbstractBase() {}
  virtual void Function() =  0;
};

template<class T>
class CRTPBase {
public:
  void Function2() {}
};

class Derived : public AbstractBase, public CRTPBase<Derived> {
public:
  void Function() {}
};

int main () {
  Derived d;
  d.Function();
  d.Function2();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Can a class inherit from both an abstract class and a CRTP class?

Why not? Yes, it can.

> Or if I inherit from a CRTP class must all classes I inherit from use CRTP?

Why so? No, they don't have to.